# Sonata Admin Bundle 4.5 ListView: Link again directly to /edit instead of /show

Tags: symfony, symfony4, sonata-admin

We just updated our project to symfony 4.4 and Sonata Admin 4.5. It works so far, but in the list view we are now directed to `/[modelName]/[classId]/show` instead of the old behaviour of ging directly to `/[modelName]/[classId]/edit`

Is there a way to configure the 4.5 admin bundle, so that we can jump straight to the entity edit view again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question 2 days ago !
Instead of changing every Admin file you can just change the configuration in `sonata_admin.yaml`

```yaml
sonata_admin:
    options:
        default_admin_route: edit
        skin: 'skin-black'
```

Comment: Awesome! Let me try this - if it works, I'll mark this the right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turned out the [documentation is our friend](https://docs.sonata-project.org/projects/SonataAdminBundle/en/3.x/reference/routing/#changing-the-default-route-in-a-list-action) :)

```php
final class YourEntitiyAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->add('id')  
            ->addIdentifier('name', null, [
                'route' => [
                    'name' => 'edit' // <-- this changes from /show to /edit
                ]
            ])
            // whatever other field you want
            ;
    }
}
```